# Pandas cells with list's as values: Remove NA values in the list's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` where some cells have values of type `list()`. Some elements of the list are `numpy.nan`. I want to remove the `nan` elements from that lists. This is because I want to do a `str.join()` the elements of the list to one string.

This is the example data

```
   A         B
0  1    [a, b]
1  2  [c, nan]
2  3       [e]
```

The result should look like this:

```
   A       B
0  1  [a, b]
1  2     [c]
2  3     [e]
```

My question is if my solution is fine or if there is a more elegant pandas way to do this?

I am aware that one solution could be to replace the `nan` values with something else, e.g. an empty string ``. But this is not part of that scenario.

This is the MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env pyhton3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initial data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan, 'e']
    }
)

# create cells with list-values
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(list)
df = df.reset_index()

print(df)

df.B = df.B.transform(lambda x: list(pd.Series(x).dropna()))

print(df)

# By the way:
# This was my goal but it is not possible with 'NA' values in the lists.
df.B = df.B.transform(lambda x: ' | '.join(x))

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jezrael mentioned, you remove the NaN in generator comprehension.

You also can directly do this in the `agg` groupby call.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan, 'e']
    }
)

df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda l: ' | '.join(x for x in l if pd.notna(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `NaN` in generator comprehension if there are lists with missing values or `None`s like `Nonetype`:

```
df.B = df.B.transform(lambda x: ' | '.join(y for y in x if pd.notna(y)))
```

Or if possible remove missing rows before `groupby`:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['B']).groupby('A')['B'].agg(' | '.join).reset_index()
print(df)
   A      B
0  1  a | b
1  2      c
2  3      e
```